# how to make html syntax in php $content to look better?

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code

so i have a template php which looks something like this:

```
<body>
<header></header>
<?php
echo $content;
?>
<footer></footer>
</body>
```

and i have an index php which looks like this:

```
<?php

$content = '
*html syntax here*
*html syntax here*
*html syntax here*
'

include 'template.php';

?>
```

im using visual studio code and this works perfectly. however, the html syntax inside the `$content` is all green and it makes it very hard to read. it also does not format itself although im using prettier to make the code easier to read. is there a way i could make it easier to read or is there a better way to do this? thank you so much in advance im very new to php.

Comment: The html inside the PHP is not seen as HTML, it's just a string, i.e. plain text. The editor has no way of knowing really that you want it to be treated as HTML. I could be wrong but as far as I know you can't really do anything about that unfortunately.

Comment: PhpStorm recognizes HTML inside strings, so maybe the answer is to switch to a better IDE.

Comment: There might be some variation when using HEREDOC strings. Though that still depends on how smart the IDE syntax highlighter is.

Comment: try installing themes I have used Github look alike theme from marketplace. I sorted lot of my issues visually speaking.